# Error with import BAR-File from OBIEE 12.2.1.0.0 to 12.2.1.2.0

Tags: oracle, migration, weblogic, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm facing an error by importing the BAR-File of Version 12.2.1.0.0 to 12.2.1.2.0 importing it with `importserviceinstance()`.

It is not a Linux machine, so I use the .cmd files like the wlst.cmd to export and import the BAR-File.

Export: `exportServiceInstance(r'C:\DOMAIN_HOME','ssi',r'C:\WORK',r'C:\EXPORT','','','',true,'password')`

So I used the option to export also all the user content by setting the second last to true.

Import: `importServiceInstance(r'C:\DOMAIN_HOME','ssi',r'C:\EXPORT\ssi.bar',true,true,true,'password')`

And here I set every option to true, to get everything (RPD, webcat, security Settings).

This is the error message prompted :

```
...

oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler importServiceInstance
SEVERE: Failed in running importServiceInstance for plugin oracle.bi.migration.webcat.WebcatMetadataManagerGenericPlugin
Impl
oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper logErrorMessages
SEVERE: An error has occurred while executing command, Please check Catalog Manager log for more details.
oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.ServiceInstanceFrameWorkImpl importServiceInstance
SEVERE: Error during import service instance for handler oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler

PM oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl importServiceInstance
SEVERE: Failed in running all the handlers during import service instance.

...
```

I've already checked the catalog manager logs, but this didn't help much to locate the problem.

Has anyone already faced the same error or has an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: "I've already checked the catalog manager logs" <-- So can you paste them here? 


Failing that, best raise an SR to Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond Robin, it wasn't possible to post the logs because of security issues. We've switched now on a Linux Server and it works.

Comment: Life is always easier on Linux ;-)

Answer (score 0):

on windows, your path need to be modified from backslashes to forward

example:
instead of C:\DOMAIN_HOME you can use C:/DOMAIN_HOME

this is for all paths in the wlst commands